# Como criar um menu de tabs como o do Stack Overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para ter dois links como abas, por exemplo:

```
<a href="#">Abrir Elemento 01</a>
<a href="#">Abrir Elemento 02</a>
```

e ao clicar em um desses links abrir uma `div` com o conteúdo correspondente a cada link clicado, ou seja:

> Ao clicar em **`Abrir Elemento 01`** `=>` Abre uma div com o **`Conteúdo 01`**.
>   Ao clicar em **`Abrir Elemento 02`** `=>` Abre o **`Conteúdo 02`**.

e enquanto essa `div` estiver aberta, o nome dessa `tab` fique realçado, e a `div` aberta com o conteúdo só fechasse se o usuário clicasse fora da `div` ou em `Fechar Elemento`.

O meu objetivo é criar um menu como o menu de notificações do Stack Overflow.
Obrigado desde já.

Comment: O que você quer se chama diálogo modal. Tem várias bibliotecas pra isso.

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sua pergunta está um pouco vaga e difícil de entender o que realmente você está tentando fazer, para que possa dar uma resposta concreta e adaptar o código da melhor forma.

No entanto vou postar aqui um conceito de como podes alcançar o pretendido e depois então podes fazer às alterações necessárias para as suas necessidades.

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.elemnto-link');
var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

// cria loop para todos os elementos com a class "elemento-link" 
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++ ){
    link = x[i];
    // Adiciona evento click
    link.addEventListener('click', function(evento) {
        // Verifica o id do elemento clicado
        if (evento.target.id == 'el-um'){
            // Se o id coincidir com o primeiro link "el-um", adiciona este texto no "resultado"
            resultado.innerHTML = '<span class="conteudo-resultado">Conteúdo do elemento UM</span>';
        } else if (evento.target.id == 'el-dois') {
            // Se o id coincidir com o segundo link "el-dois", adiciona este texto
            resultado.innerHTML = '<span class="conteudo-resultado">Conteúdo do elemento DOIS</span>';
        } else if (evento.target.id == 'fechar') {
            // Se coincidir com o elemento "fechar", elimina o texto dentro do resultado
            resultado.innerHTML = '';
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.elemnto-link {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.conteudo-resultado {
    display: block;
    background-color: royalblue;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span id="el-um" class="elemnto-link">Abrir Elemento 01</span>
<span id="el-dois" class="elemnto-link">Abrir Elemento 02</span>
<span id="fechar" class="elemnto-link">fechar</span>

<div id="resultado"></div>
```

---

### >_Edição

Para fazer um **menu de tabs** como o do Stack Overflow, até podes fazê-lo apenas com CSS da seguinte maneira:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navegacao {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.navegacao span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 16px;
    outline: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navegacao span:hover,
.navegacao span:active,
.navegacao span:focus {
    background-color: #eee;
}
.nav-um:focus ~ .conteudo .conteudo-um,
.nav-um:active ~ .conteudo .conteudo-um {
    display: block;
}
.nav-dois:focus ~ .conteudo .conteudo-dois,
.nav-dois:active ~ .conteudo .conteudo-dois {
    display: block;
}
.nav-tres:focus ~ .conteudo .conteudo-tres,
.nav-tres:active ~ .conteudo .conteudo-tres {
    display: block;
}

.conteudo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}
.same {
    display:none;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navegacao">
    <span class="nav-um" tabindex="1">X</span>
    <span class="nav-dois" tabindex="2">Y</span>
    <span class="nav-tres" tabindex="3">Z</span>
    <div class="conteudo">
        <div class="conteudo-um same">Conteúdo do elemento UM</div>
        <div class="conteudo-dois same">Conteúdo do elemento DOIS</div>
        <div class="conteudo-tres same">Conteúdo do elemento TRÊS</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### Conteúdo desaparece quando o mesmo é clicado

Para resolver esse problema poderíamos apenas adicionar também um `tabindex=""` aos `conteúdos` e agregar um focus ao conjunto responsabilizado por mostrar o conteúdo:

```
.nav-um:focus ~ .conteudo .conteudo-um,
.nav-um:active ~ .conteudo .conteudo-um,
.conteudo-um:focus, .conteudo-um:active     /* Novo focus para o conteúdo */
{
    display: block;
}
```

Isto resultava, mas também iria resultar em um novo problema, que é perder o focus da tab com título que não temos como manipular isso para ele se manter `ativo` ou seja, com aquela cor de background cinzenta quando o conteúdo é clicado, então aqui teremos de recorrer a um pouco de Javascript, neste caso jQuery da seguinte forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navegacao span').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('tab-ativada')) {
            $('.navegacao span').removeClass('tab-ativada');
            $('.same').focus();
        } else {
            $('.navegacao span').removeClass('tab-ativada');
            $(this).addClass('tab-ativada');
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        if (!$(e.target).is('.navegacao span, .same')) {
            $('.navegacao span').removeClass('tab-ativada');  
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navegacao {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.navegacao span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 16px;
    outline: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-ativada, .navegacao span:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
}

/* Isto poderia ser dividido em três blocos de código como estava anteriormente, mas já que o estilo a ser aplicado é igual para todos decidi juntar tudo num só bloco. Adapta-o à tua maneira */

/* Primeira Tab */
.nav-um:focus ~ .conteudo .conteudo-um,
.nav-um:active ~ .conteudo .conteudo-um,
.conteudo-um:focus, .conteudo-um:active,

/* Segunda Tab */
.nav-dois:focus ~ .conteudo .conteudo-dois,
.nav-dois:active ~ .conteudo .conteudo-dois,
.conteudo-dois:focus, .conteudo-dois:active,

/* Terceira Tabe */
.nav-tres:focus ~ .conteudo .conteudo-tres,
.nav-tres:active ~ .conteudo .conteudo-tres,
.conteudo-tres:focus, .conteudo-tres:active {
    display: block;
}

.conteudo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}
.same {
    display:none;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navegacao">
    <span class="nav-um" tabindex="1">X</span>
    <span class="nav-dois" tabindex="2">Y</span>
    <span class="nav-tres" tabindex="3">Z</span>
    <div class="conteudo">
        <div class="conteudo-um same" tabindex="1">Conteúdo do elemento UM</div>
        <div class="conteudo-dois same" tabindex="2">Conteúdo do elemento DOIS</div>
        <div class="conteudo-tres same" tabindex="3">Conteúdo do elemento TRÊS</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pra deixar mais claro, é um menu parecido com a "notificações" do stackoverflow

Comment: Explicado dessa maneira seria bem mais fácil de entender aquilo que estavas a tentar alcançar @mayron2017 xD

Comment: Cʜᴜɴ amigo encontrei um problema, ao clicar dentro do `conteudo- um `conteudo- dois `conteudo- tres` ele fecha a div, e o objetivo é so fechar se for clicado fora da `div` ou no `menu`

Comment: Fiz uma nova edição @mayron2017

Comment: Só tem um outro problema amigo, a div não fecha ao clicar no menu, só fecha ao clicar fora, mais vou testar no meu sistema

Comment: E porque se eu colocar a `nav-um` `nav-dois` `nav-tres` dentro de uma `ul li`, ele não funciona, sendo que eu aterei no `js` também pra `.navegacao ul li span`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v05wrq12/

Comment: perfeito, e desculpa pela insistencia

Answer (score 1):

Podes criar com o slideToggle do JQuery:

```
<a title="Abre o Elemento 01" class="element--01" href="javascript:void(0)">Abrir Elemento 01</a>

<a title="Abre o Elemento 02" class="element--02" href="javascript:void(0)">Abrir Elemento 02</a>


<div class="abrir--01" style="display:none">Olá Mundo!</div>
<div class="abrir--02" style="display:none">Olá Mundo!</div>
```

---

```
$(function(){
    $('.element--1').click(function(){
          $('.abrir--01').slideToggle('fast');
    });

    $('.element--2').click(function(){
          $('.abrir--02').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: Não funcionou amigo

Comment: Em seu site ja tem o JQuery instalado?

Comment: Sim pego direto da biblioteca